# How to reload a view using Angularjs using a timeout?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm building a simple dashboard, where I have multiple views.
I would like to set a refresh time - around 60 seconds - to automatically refresh the view the user has selected.

Here is a block of my Angular app:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "dashHome.html"
    })
    .when("/OverallView", {
        templateUrl : "dashOverallView.html"
    })
    .when("/DetailedView", {
        templateUrl : "dashDetailedView.html"
    })
    .when("/GraphicView", {
        templateUrl : "dashGraphicView.html"
    })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl : "dashHome.html"
    });
});
```

So, let's say, the user is on the OverallView. I would like to refresh this view every 60 seconds, without reloading all page. Just the view.

How can I do that?

Comment: why you need to reload the view when you can simply refresh the scope and it will reflect the data changes on view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $route.reload();

AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route):

> Causes $route service to reload the current route even if $location hasn't changed.
>
> As a result of that, ngView creates new scope, reinstantiates the controller.

Call it on your controller within a $timeout